# Membership import - is there any column heading that will automatically match internal identifier?

Tags: import

I've tried all sorts of things and can't find any column heading for the cvs that will automatically match internal identifier.  One would think that if you use what comes up when you manually match that it would automatically match to that, but not really.

I've figured out that the following will match:
join matches with membership since.
start matches with membership start date
end matches with membership expiration date

Funny Gender matches to membership start date

Comment: I've used "Membership Type" as a heading on csv and it matches perfectly for type of membership used for import and "Contact ID" to match the id. This is on the latest version 4.6.9.

Comment: I've imported lots and lots of membership and tried all sorts of things over the years.  Not sure why I couldn't get membership type to work because now I can.  But the other is the external identifier and not the contact id.  Since I'm import new contacts and their memberships, I import the contacts first with an external identifier so next I can import the memberships and link to the external identifier.